# How can Upload a file to Sharepoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, request, httpurlconnection

```
private void uploadDocToSharePoint(String token, Resource resource, String folderName) {
    try {
        String uploadUrl = Utils.SHARE_POINT_DOMAIN + "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderName + "')/files/add(url='" + resource.getFilename() + "', overwrite=true)";
        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set Header
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        OutputStream os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        osw.write("Just Some Text");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        os.close();  //don't forget to close the OutputStream
        httpConn.connect();


        System.out.println(httpConn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(httpConn.getResponseMessage());
        String result;
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int result2 = bis.read();
        while(result2 != -1) {
            buf.write((byte) result2);
            result2 = bis.read();
        }
        result = buf.toString();
        System.out.println(result);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

`httpConn.getResponseCode()` is `400` and `httpConn.getResponseMessage()` is `Bad Request`.

I have tested this request with the URL generated in this class on `Postman`.
it works correctly.
so I am sure about url and token is correct.
It creates an Empty file successfully.
But as I mentioned the response status is `400` and `Bad Request`.

I am not sure what is wrong with the following class

Sharepoint guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#filecollection-methods)

My class copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305351/how-do-you-send-data-in-a-request-body-using-httpurlconnection)

screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBZaM.png)

Comment: "Content-Type = application/xml" versus "Just Some Text" ?

Comment: what do you means? @DirkDeyne

Comment: I've trid after masked the "Content-Type = application/xml". but same issue

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: pls reply as answer @DirkDeyne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls follow Sharepoint guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#filecollection-methods)